# JS How to get value of my next span in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to get the text value of the span `.vypis` in this table?
I need to access the corresponding `.vypis` with a keyup on `.key`.

PHP & HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="textarea" class="key" type="text" name="item-ks" value="1"/></td>
      <td><span class="vypis">5</span>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $(".key").keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val(); // works
        var text = $(this).find(".vypis").text(); // doesn't work
        alert(text); // test is null
        $('.vypis').text(value * text);
    })
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why dont you direct access it `$(".vypis").text()`

Answer (score 2):

The input and span elements are nested in TD's _

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find(".vypis").text();
```

So all together like this :

```
$(function(){
    $(".key").on('keyup', function(){
        var value = this.value,
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find(".vypis").text(function(_,txt) {
            return parseInt(txt, 10) * parseInt(value, 10);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(this).find(".vypis").text();
```

to:

```
$(this).closest().next().find(".vypis").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this to get `span` text

```
var text = $(this).closest('td').next().find(".vypis").text();
```